# How to authenticate .NET2 Webservice with a SQUID proxy

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, squid

I've got a little utility that is a SOAP WebService client. The SOAP-proxy is generated from WSDL. It was working fine.

Now the customer wants to use a SQUID proxy, but that refuses to authenticate my SOAP client.

I have already tried:

```
 MyWebservice ws = new MyWebservice();
 // set URL etc.
 // login for the actual service, this part works
 HeaderLogin hl = new HeaderLogin();
 hl.username = svcLogin;
 hl.password = svcPassword;
 ws.HeaderLoginValue = hl;

 // setting up the Proxy of the Proxy
 //ws.Proxy = System.Net.WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
 ws.Proxy = System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;

 //ws.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;                
 ws.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyUser, proxyPassword, proxyDomain);
```

But I keep getting the HTTP 407 error: Proxy authentication required.

SQUID (squid/2.7.STABLE4) is setup to use NTLM and AD for the authentication. That seems to work OK: there are other WebService clients that are getting through the Proxy OK.

I don't have direct access to the site but only some logfiles to look at. Most remarkable is what I can see in the PCAP (Wireshark) files. When I create a NetworkCredential with userName="Henk", domain="TEST" it shows up in the PCAP as

> ...  HTTP CONNECT someurl:443 HTTP/1.1 , NTLMSSP_AUTH, User: T\H

And when I look at the PCAP for a working service

> ... HTTP CONNECT someurl:443 HTTP/1.0 , NTLMSSP_AUTH, User: TEST\Henk

And in the SQUID acces.log all attempts are shown as:

> ...      0 192.168.15.95 TCP_DENIED/407 1759 CONNECT someurl:443 - NONE/- text/html
>   ...     32 192.168.15.95 TCP_DENIED/407 2055 CONNECT someurl:443 - NONE/- text/html
>   ...     31 192.168.15.95 TCP_DENIED/407 1759 CONNECT someurl:443 - NONE/- text/html

Concrete questions:

- any known issues with .NET2 SOAP and Squid?
- is the display of TEST\Henk as T\H significant?
- anything else I should be looking for?

Comment: Random thing to check: where are proxyUser, proxyPassword, and proxyDomain coming from? Is it possible they are accidentally incorrect before reaching this point? `proxyUser = form.Fields["proxyUser"][0]` instead of `proxyUser = form.Fields["proxyUser"]` maybe?

Comment: @Stobor: Good point but I would call that 'systematic', not 'random'. It is all checked and double-checked.

Comment: @Henk - did you ever solve this? I'm hitting the same problem using WebClient which is refusing to authenticate with a Squid proxy despite the fact that all browsers authenticate with the proxy fine, and the WebClient works if I disable authentication.

Comment: @RobLevine - sorry for the late reaction. No, I never got this to work, the setup was changed.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that the NTLM connection is being recycled before the connection is completed resulting in a new/second anonymous connection request and the 407 error.

Try overriding the GetWebRequest(Uri uri) method and set the [KeepAlive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive.aspx) property to false.

Edit the Reference.cs file with the following:

```
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
{
   HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
   webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
   return webRequest;
}
```

Just remember that updating the web reference will cause Visual Studio to regenerate the file and you'll need to modify the file again.

Comment: I'm not able to test this before next week but I would guess it's not the problem, I can see in the logs that other (working) clients also use KeepAlive=true.

Answer (score 2):

The T\H could be an indication that you have Unicode string being used as ASCII string. Since Unicode characters are two bytes (the most common case on Windows), if you interpret them as ASCII you get the real character and a null terminator byte.

I wouldn't expect to see that type of error in a .NET app, but you never know.

Comment: I'll try tomorrow but I think there is a flag in the headers called UnicodeNegotiate. The T\H thing could come from WireShark too.

Comment: You can look at the raw bytes in WireShark, which will show you whether it is WireShark or just the sender of the data.

Comment: I like this suggestion, did you test it Henk?

Comment: the ASCII setting (on the SOAP client) didn't work. The pcap shows that the full name, domain and password are there (always in UTF-16). So I guess the single-char thing is from WireShark.

Answer (score 0):

I see that squid log shows access denied to **someurl:443**... port 443 is a secure channel port (SSL). In common practice webservices hosted on SSL require some sort of a authentication. please check the webservice credential requirements. you may have to pass the credentials or authenticate yourself as a valid client through a certificate.

Comment: ajay, you're right but we have all that (and working). It's just the proxy and the 407 error blocking us.

Comment: can you try setting "http_access allow" to the domain in your squid config

Answer (score 0):

can you try add "http_access allow" to the domain in your squid config